# Converting formatted html text to svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am looking for a javascript tool/lib which can convert formatted html text (font tags, margins etc) into svg. I am using bootstrap-wysiwyg to enable rich text input but need to get the result converted into native svg. The initial html is something like:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Go <font face="Sans">ahead</font>… and&nbsp;
<blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
    <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
        <div><font size="15" face="Impact">by the&nbsp;</font></div>
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
<div>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><font size="15" face="Courier New" style="color: inherit;">way</font><span
            style="color: inherit;">&nbsp;</span></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: inherit;">all is now</span></div>
</div>
```

which can get pretty complex after playing around with the editor features a bit. Alternative i would be very happy to find a similar javascript WIWhSWYG rich text editor which creates native svg straight away yet i haven't found anything so far.

Any pointer highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
While still looking for a complete solution I am experimenting right now with
http://quilljs.com/
which seems very promising as it at least does half of the job for you. It has a very handy API through which you can get the representation of the current text with all its format information as an array of Text/Format Objects (called Deltas in its own terminology) . These Deltas are a very good starting point to create the desired SVG texts, particular if you, as in my case, only need a small subset of the common rich editor features.

Comment: If the resultant SVGs are going to only be displayed in a browser, you can use an `<foreignObject>`element to embedd HTML in your SVG.  If that's not acceptable then have you tried googling?  I found at least two different tools that way.

Comment: Thank BigBababook, i was looking into that also yet I need the ability to use the text as a masking path so the foreinObject won't do for me. Nevertheless thanks again for commenting.

Comment: I know how to do it with http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.TryIt. The back end supports SVG as well as PDF output. It will take a day to turn on SVG support on the backend server.

Comment: Actually this link is better, we were in the process of implementing an editor anyway http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Development.TestSummerNote ...

Comment: It gets messy with SVG when you join different font sizes on same line. Basically you're re-writing MS word engine for SVG.

Comment: Thx Kevin yet the idea is not to use an external service for that.

Comment: Yep Alvin, i get this feeling too ;-) fortunately i need only a few features of MS Words. Right now i am experimenting with http://quilljs.com/ which has a handy API through which you can get the editor content in an array of objects of textelements, looks promising.

Comment: Alvin, just sharing an insight i just had, it seems <tspan> enables you to use different font sizes etc (style elements) within one line without having to worry about the positioning ... just for the case that might be of some help

Comment: @dorjeduck: `<tspan>` on a single line is easy, gets tricky with multiple lines, each line contains different font size & family. Another tough cookie is SVG line-wrap. quilljs.com uses HTML, not SVG though.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, i will see how I get along. Yes quills uses HTML, but it has an abstract representation of the editor content (Deltas) which are much easier to handle with than having to parse the actual html - well for me, my first prototype looks promising so far ...

Comment: No prob. The service is there as free to use for folks. Those that do not desire an external service have the option to implement on their servers but it is commercially licensed then.

Answer (score 1):

See

http://quotemirror.com/lab/quilljsGoesSVG/

for an unpolished proof of concept hack to convert [quilljs.com](http://quilljs.com/) editor input into svg. Only a few basic editor features are implemented. Key in this implementation is the usage of the abstract representation of the formatted editor input - deltas -  which [quilljs.com](http://quilljs.com/) is offering through its marvelous API . This demo might be buggy yet is meant to show one way to implement this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As above, another example. Content editable div. This is making an SVG of the whole area including the heading, but you can configure the JS to format any DIV you like.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.TryIt

We have only wired to download now, select the download button and select SVG.

Most all the demos on this page work in the same way. We are only working through sizing characteristics of SVG inserted into other SVG (for the charting demos).

Web site on left, SVG result on right in image below.

[image]

Comment: Thx Kevin, interesting to know yet in my case i am looking for a javascript solution to be used in a program.